# reversing jquery click on each click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write some jQuery that will switch the temperature between fahrenheit and celsius each time I click on the weather div. Here is what I have for the initial click:

```
$('#weather').on('click', function() {
            // $('#author').hide('fast')
            $('#weather').empty();
            $('#weather').append(`
            <h2>Weather</h2>
            <h4>${weather.name}</h4>
            <h3>${Math.round(weather.main.temp - 273.15)} &#176C</h3>
            <h5>${weather.weather[0].description}</h5>
        `)
```

Any insight on how to make it switch back to Fahrenheit after the initial click?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could toggle a class on element and check that class

```
$('#weather').on('click', function() {
     var $elem = $(this).empty(),
         isCelsius = $elem.hasClass('celsius');
     $elem.toggleClass('celsius');

     var value = isCelsius ? /* calc Fahrenheit */ : /*calc celsius*/;
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something simple like this:
Have both on the page and toggle them.

```js
$('.fahrenheit').hide();
$('.celsius, .fahrenheit').on('click', function()  {
  $('.celsius, .fahrenheit').toggle()
});
```

```css
.celsius{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:#eee;
    float:left;    
}

.fahrenheit{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:#fdcb05;
    float:left;     
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="celsius">
    <p> xy Celsius </p>
</div>
<div class="fahrenheit" >
    <p> zw Fahrenheit  </p>
</div>
```